# Bypassing game objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a 3D game using Unity 3D. I'm posting the following question here because its a general coding question that doesn't answer only to the Unity platform.

I have several game objects in my scene, each have a vector of three points representing their locations. All placed on the same plane so they share the same Y coardinate . No, in my scene I'm moving one game object to a specific location, and I want to avoid any collision between the moving object and any other one. In fact, I want to make a bypass\detour if I'm about to hit other game object.

Is there a general implementation of such a detour\bypass? Is there an API I can use to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ways to achieve. The easiest code free would be if your movement was utilizing the nav mesh you could set him to automatically move around the object like it would a obstacle. The other that comes to mind would be using A* path finding and again he would treat it like a obstacle and move around.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called path finding,
I am not familiar with this but you can find a lot of good articles that explain it very well.

http://homepages.abdn.ac.uk/f.guerin/pages/teaching/CS1013/practicals/aStarTutorial.htm

I don't know unity but I think you will have to develop the path finding algorithm yourself.